# Link column with link to a file in static (django-tables2, Django)

Tags: django, django-tables2

I generate a table with django-tables within Django.
I want to create a column with links to txt files in my static directory.
When the user clicks on the link, the txt file should be displayed.

To create a link to the txt file within an html, I simply do:

```
<a href="{% static co.log %}">txtfile</a>
```

However, I have problems finding the right way to do this using django-tables.
I tried to define the link column as follows:

```
logfiles = tables.LinkColumn('{static', text='txtfile', args=[A('log')], orderable=False, empty_values=())
```

This gives the error 
"Reverse for '{static' not found. '{static' is not a valid view function or pattern name."

I also tried this:

**tables.py**

```
logfiles = tables.LinkColumn('logfile', text='bla', orderable=False, empty_values=())
```

**urls.py:**

```
url(r'^logfile/', views.logfile, name='logfile')
```

**views.py:**

```
def logfile(request):
return HttpResponse('<p>yeah</p>')
```

So I can find a way to open a new url, but how to open a specific static file, i.e.how to pass the info from [A('log')], which is basically the filename?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [`TemplateColumn`](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/api-reference.html#templatecolumn) to achieve this:

```
class LogTable(tables.Table):
    log = tables.TemplateColumn(
        template_code='{% load static %}<a href="{% static value %}">txtfile</a>'
    )
```

Note that the column name is `log`, so there is no need to specify the accessor. If you want the color to appear with a different name, use the `verbose_name` kwarg.