# Link column to file in static subdirectory; django-tables2

Tags: django, django-tables2

I am trying to use django-tables2 to render a table where one of the columns is a link to a file. The [Link column with link to a file in static (django-tables2, Django)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49947343/link-column-with-link-to-a-file-in-static-django-tables2-django)  response is quite close however, in my case I have placed my files in `static/pfd/`.

```
pdf = tables.TemplateColumn(template_code='{% load static %}<a href="{% static value %}">{{record.pdf}}</a>')
```

**please note {{record.pdf}} will show the name of the pdf when rendered.

This snippet of code works *if* my pdf is in the static directory, otherwise I get an missing file error. I have tried to add the subdirectory, but when I do I get an invalid syntax error.

```
pdf = tables.TemplateColumn(template_code='{% load static %}<a href="{% static 'pdf/' %}">{{record.pdf}}</a>')
                                                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I update that line so that the path is correct and will result in this url:

```
http://xx.xx.xx.xxx:8000/static/pdf/lapidus_1_0.pdf
```

Instead of:

```
http://xx.xx.xx.xxx:8000/static/lapidus_1_0.pdf
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `{% static 'pdf/lapidus_1_0.pdf' %}`?

Comment: I don't think that will address my issue, I am rendering a table where each table row/entry will have a unique file.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the question. Is the value `{{record.pdf}}` the name of the pdf file in `static`?

Comment: Yes, {{record.pdf}} will show the correct filename, but the file is located in static/pdf/. I can see how that is confusing, I will make a note of it in the question.

Comment: Wait, have you tried using `(template_code='''{% load static %} etc...''')`? If you are using the given code, `pdf/` is not part of a string due to the single quotes around it. That would be the syntax error you're seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
pdf = tables.TemplateColumn(template_code=
  '''{% load static %}<a href="{% static 'pdf/'|add:value %}">{{record.pdf}}</a>''')
```

That will add the `value` created by the `TemplateColumn` to the end of `'pdf/'`. For more information on `value` and the other context items used with `TemplateColumn`, see the [docs](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/api-reference.html#templatecolumn).

Also, as noted in my comment, use triple quotes `'''` so double and single quotes are both treated as characters within the string. `pdf/` was escaped, causing the `SyntaxError`.

Comment: I appreciate you effort, but it does not work. `pdf = tables.TemplateColumn(template_code='{% load static %}<a href="{% static 'pdf/'|add:value %}">{{record.pdf}}</a>')
                                                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: You still haven't surrounded it with triple quotes. This is necessary.

Comment: Glad to help! The documentation for the `TemplateColumn` (which I will link in my answer shortly) lists the variables it uses, including `value` used in this example. `add:` shows up for a search on how to concatenate strings in Django templates.